# In tmux, after ssh a server, how to send R code in vim to R consol

Tags: linux, ssh, vim, tmux

I installed tmux and  vim-r-plugin in local machine (ref: http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r/vim-r), and use ssh to log in a server (only vim-r-plugin and screen installed). But in vim, I cannot send code to R consol. I  am confused with the tmux. Should I also install tmux in a server? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We always work with terminals , one for vim , second for ssh and third to play with bash command  ...etc , and we move between them .
Tmux let us manage all this and more inside one terminal window , [This tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-tmux--net-33889) will help you understand its approach.

You don't need to install it in your server , and tmux is not your problem .

The author suggest using UNIX-like working environment, if your local machine is then you don't have to ssh to a server . If you have no problem with R then check [vim-r-plugin](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/r-plugin.html#r-plugin-installation) installed properly

Comment: Actually, I can run R in vim in the local, but when I sshed into  server. the function does not work. I want to use vim and R in the sever. The tutorial seems no hints about this. Thank you.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking, OP wants to know how to send R code to an R instance running on the server.  My initial thought is run vim + vim-r-plugin on the server.